# Change text forth and back inside a div

Tags: jquery, text, html

I have a small problem with a text area inside a div and a span tag. What it does, is to be a href for opening a drop-down div, and when clicked again on the text it closes that div.

```
<a href="#" id="toggle4">
    <span class="halfCircleBottom">OPEN</span>
</a>
```

So what I want to achieve is, when I click on OPEN, it should change to CLOSE, and when I click back on CLOSE it should change to OPEN. Everything I've found so far is to change the text once, but  not back again to the original value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('span.halfCircleBottom').click(function(){
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML === "OPEN" ? "CLOSE" : "OPEN";
});
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gwHDb/)

Comment: That's it! Thank you all for helping me out! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#cf_onclick").toggle(
        function(){$(this).html("<h2>A</h2>");},
        function(){$(this).html("<h2>B</h2>");}
    ).click();
});
```

Another Method

```
$('#toggle_template').html(function(i, html) {
        if (html.indexOf(' (click to view)') > 1) {
            return html.replace(' (click to view)', ' (click to close)')
        }
        return html.replace(' (click to close)', ' (click to view)')
    });
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/ufXxb/79/)

2nd Method [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/m998n/136/)

Comment: This toggle overload was removed in version 1.9. _"Note: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9."_

Comment: `if (html.indexOf(' (click to view)') > 1)` should be `> -1`

Answer (score 1):

That's easy with JQuery :)

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="btnclick()"><span class="halfCircleBottom">OPEN</span></a>
```

JS:

```
function btnclick() {
 $('#divID').slideToggle();
  if ($('.halfCircleBottom').text() == "CLOSE"){
  $('.halfCircleBottom').text("OPEN")
  } else {
  $('.halfCircleBottom').text("CLOSE")
  }
}
```

When clicked, it will change the text to OPEN or close and also slide the div up and down. This is really easy to understand :)